# Scipy.ode "Error test failed repeatedly"

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve a system of coupled complex ODEs in python using scipy.ode with zvode integrator. But this error message shows up once I run the code.

```
ZVODE--  At T(=R1) and step size H(=R2), the error test failed repeatedly or with abs(H) = HMIN. In above,  R1 =  0.1018805870139D-15   R2 =  0.2392554739952D-22
```

I did take a look at the FORTRAN source code but was unable to figure out what it implied.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Edit : The code has been included.
I also tried printing out a few values and also wrote a separate code for the integration that employs the simple Euler method. From these I have a feeling that the error could be due to values getting out of range, i.e greater than 10^308. (probably due to errors in some parameters). Could anyone please confirm this ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.integrate import ode

# Constants
h_cross = 6.5821e-16 
charge = 1 
a = 5.65e-10
gamma = 1/50e-15 
E_g = 1.43  
temp = 300
k_b = 8.6173e-5  



k = np.linspace(-1, 1, 32) * np.pi / a 
k = k[1:]
grad_k = k[1] - k[0]  

delta_c_1 = 6.9
delta_v = 1

e_c_1 = delta_c_1/2.0 * (1 - np.cos(np.abs(k * a))) + E_g/2.0
e_v = -delta_v/2.0 * (1 - np.cos(np.abs(k * a))) - E_g/2.0
t_0 = 1e-14 # Initial time
dt = 5e-15 # Time interval 
t_f = t_0 + 50e-14 # Final time
t_mid = (t_0 + t_f) / 2.0
steps = int((t_f - t_0) / dt) 
t = np.linspace(t_0,t_f,steps)

d = np.ones(k.size) * 3.336e-30 


w_0 = 0.1 / h_cross
f_0 = w_0 / (2*np.pi)

y_0 = np.zeros([k.size,3],dtype = complex)
y_input = y_0.flatten()

solution = y_input # Inserting initial condition as the first entry in the solution

def E(times):
    pulse = np.cos(w_0 * times ) 
    fwhm = 10e-14
    sigma = fwhm / 2.35 
    envelope = ( 1 / (2 * np.pi *sigma**2)**0.5 ) * np.exp( -((times-t_mid)/sigma)**2 / 2.0)
    waveform = pulse * envelope 
    return waveform

# NORMALIZE VALUE OF E(t) USING VALUE AT PEAK VALUE OF E(t)
E_peak_req = 1e8
E_peak = E(t).max()
normalisation = np.abs(E_peak_req / E_peak) * (1/1.6e-19)


def dynamics(t,y):

    dydt = np.zeros([k.size,3],dtype = complex)


    if(solution.size == (k.size*3)):
        prev_y = solution
        prev_y = np.reshape(prev_y,(k.size,3))
        prev_prev_y = prev_y
        prev_prev_y = np.reshape(prev_prev_y,(k.size,3))
    else:
        last_step = solution.shape[0] - 1
        prev_y = solution[last_step,:]
        prev_y = np.reshape(prev_y,(k.size,3)) # Extracting the latest values of the density matrix elements obtained in the last time step 
        prev_prev_y = solution[last_step - 1, :] 
        prev_prev_y = np.reshape(prev_prev_y,(k.size,3))

    for index in range(k.size):

        grad_p = prev_y[index][0] - prev_prev_y[index][0]
        grad_f_c = prev_y[index][1] - prev_prev_y[index][1] 
        grad_f_v = prev_y[index][2] - prev_prev_y[index][2]

        dipole_contr =  d[index] * (E(t) * normalisation)
        grad_contr_1 = 1j * charge * (E(t) * normalisation) * grad_p / grad_k 
        grad_contr_2 = charge * (E(t) * normalisation) * grad_f_c / grad_k 
        grad_contr_3 = charge * (E(t) * normalisation) * grad_f_v / grad_k 

        dpdt = (-1j  / h_cross) * ( (e_c_1[index] + e_v[index] - 1j*h_cross*gamma) * prev_y[index][0] - (1 - prev_y[index][1] - prev_y[index][2]) * dipole_contr + grad_contr_1 )
        dfcdt = (1 / h_cross) * ( -2 * np.imag( dipole_contr * np.conjugate(prev_y[index][0]) ) + grad_contr_2 )
        dfvdt = (1 / h_cross) * ( -2 * np.imag( dipole_contr * np.conjugate(prev_y[index][0]) ) + grad_contr_3 )

        dydt[index] = np.array([dpdt, dfcdt, dfvdt])
    dydt = dydt.flatten()
    return dydt



solver = ode(dynamics, jac = None).set_integrator('zvode', method ='bdf')
solver.set_initial_value(y_input, t_0) #.set_f_params()
while (solver.successful() and solver.t + dt <= t_f):
            solver.integrate(solver.t + dt)
            solution = np.vstack((solution,solver.y))

sol = np.reshape(solution,(solution.shape[0],k.size,3))
```

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without that, all you will get are guesses.  They might be very good guesses, but you'll get better answers if you show the code.

Comment: Do you have any discontinuities in your equations?  You are using `ZVODE`; are your equations  [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function)?  See the  note under the section "zvode" in the [`ode` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for the suggestion. I have included the code and some extra details that I figured out in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

It means that your system is stiff, the heuristic of the step size controller computes that it needs very small step sizes to guarantee the demanded error bounds, but the step size has become so small and thus the number of required steps so large that the accumulation of floating point noise becomes more dominant, which would imply that the controller loses control over the error accumulation. It seems that to avoid this the controller bounds the step size at about `2e-7`, a little more than `sqrt(mu)`, parts of the value of `t`.